# Replace one character in string without changing string size (C++)

Tags: c++, string

I have problem with this as when `string.replace()` works with char it changes my string length. 
This is my code:

```
vector<string>::iterator it = matrica.begin();
it = it + i;
it->replace(j,j,1,' ');
```

Comment: What do you want to replace? A char at a certain position or all chars of a certain type?

Comment: look at some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace). find the overload you're calling. what does it do.

Comment: @bamboon char at a certain position

Comment: Then simply use `operator[]`.

Comment: What's the `j` variable?

Comment: Wait, you're calling replace on the iterator?

Comment: @clcto No they used `->` to dereference it first.

Comment: @zenith true, but dereferencing the iterator gives you a `char`. You cannot call replace on a `char`.

Comment: @clcto Dereferencing a `vector<string>::iterator` gives you a `string`. You cannot dereference a `string`.

Comment: @zenith sorry, being stupid.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to understand what you're doing. Looking at the [`string::replace` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) we can see that you're calling the following overload:

```
replace(size_t pos, size_t len, size_t n, char c)
```

where

- `pos` is the position of the first character to replace,
- `len` is the number of characters to replace,
- `n` is the number of characters to copy, and
- `c` is the character to copy.

So you're replacing `j` characters with one `' '` starting from index `j`.  That indeed does change the size.

If all you want to do is replace a single character with another character, you can do one of the following:

```
it->at(j) = ' '; // with bounds-checking, safer
(*it)[j] = ' ';  // without bounds-checking, faster
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// replacing in a string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string base="this is a test string.";
    std::string str2="n example";
    std::string str3="sample phrase";
    std::string str4="useful.";

    // replace signatures used in the same order as described above:

    // Using positions:                 0123456789*123456789*12345
    std::string str=base;           // "this is a test string."
    str.replace(9,5,str2);          // "this is an example string." (1)
    str.replace(19,6,str3,7,6);     // "this is an example phrase." (2)
    str.replace(8,10,"just a");     // "this is just a phrase."     (3)
    str.replace(8,6,"a shorty",7);  // "this is a short phrase."    (4)
    str.replace(22,1,3,'!');        // "this is a short phrase!!!"  (5)

    // Using iterators:                                               0123456789*123456789*
    str.replace(str.begin(),str.end()-3,str3);                    // "sample phrase!!!"      (1)
    str.replace(str.begin(),str.begin()+6,"replace");             // "replace phrase!!!"     (3)
    str.replace(str.begin()+8,str.begin()+14,"is coolness",7);    // "replace is cool!!!"    (4)
    str.replace(str.begin()+12,str.end()-4,4,'o');                // "replace is cooool!!!"  (5)
    str.replace(str.begin()+11,str.end(),str4.begin(),str4.end());// "replace is useful."    (6)
    std::cout << str << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Comment: You've provided no context for this answer and it doesn't help answer OP's question.